# How to choose a port on Arduino Create

Tags: port-mapping

I have connected my Mega2560 Arduino to my computer; locally everything works fine - I have been able to upload and run programs.

However, on [Arduino Create](https://create.arduino.cc/editor), it shows that there's no connection to my board. I have downloaded the plugin. The [instructions](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Arduino_Genuino/getting-started-with-arduino-web-editor-on-various-platforms-4b3e4a?f=1) say to "choose a port", and in the image it displays a menu with "[board] at [port]" but in my menu there is no "at", it just says "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560" with an option to choose a flavour, but no port.

How can I choose a port and get my Arduino connected?

Comment: Which operating system? I have used it, but it was slow and not pleasant to work with.

Comment: @Jot both Windows 10 and Mac OS Mojave. Both using Chrome